# nested try catch catching the same exception

Tags: php, laravel, exception, nested, try-catch

Is it possible in nested `try` and `catch` to catch the same exception in all blocks?

For example:

```
try{
   try{
      throw new Exception("exception");
   }
   catch (Exception $exception)
   {
       echo "inner catch fires";
   }
}
catch (Exception $exception)
{
    echo "outer catch fires";
}
```

For such scenario the result would be "the inner catch fires, so the outer catch fires, too"

Comment: `throw` the same exception again in that catch block?

Comment: What did you try, and what was the outcome of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that by throwing an exception from inner catch. Such as:

```php
try {
    try {
        throw new Exception('exception');
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        echo 'inner catch fires';

        throw $exception;
    }
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    echo 'outer catch fires';
}
```